# NSURLConnectionDelegate call order

Tags: ios, http, nsurlconnection

I recently started to work with NSURLConnection in my project and I'm wondering whether or not the pattern I use to handle the received data is appropriate.

In case I get a 404 or another error, I do not actually want to do anything with the data, so it would be a waste to still append it to my object. Therefore I only want to create the data object once I get a 200 status.

Is it safe to assume that `-connection:didReceiveResponse:` is called before any of the `-connection:didReceiveData:` callbacks?

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.data appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
{
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        self.data = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed with status code %d", response.statusCode);
        [self.connection cancel];
    }
}
```

Comment: Check `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method of `NSURLConnection`. You'll love it.

Comment: I do not want to use this method. I need to handle the data in small parts in `-didReceiveData:`.

Comment: In that case, yes `connection:didReceiveResponse:` is the first one gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes
`didReceiveResponse` will call `beforeDidReceiveData`, and it is possible it get calls many time in one connection as per apple document

> You should be prepared for your delegate to receive the
>   connection:didReceiveResponse: message multiple times for a single
>   connection; this can happen if the response is in multipart MIME
>   encoding. Each time the delegate receives the
>   connection:didReceiveResponse: message, it should reset any progress
>   indication and discard all previously received data (except in the
>   case of multipart responses).

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)